# How to draw this Picture in LaTeX?

Tags: diagrams, drawing

How to draw this picture in LaTeX.

[image]

Comment: `\includegraphics{}`? If you're going to post a do-it-for-me, your chances of getting a response would improve if you asked for a picture of a duck. Otherwise, you might want to post what you've tried. This looks like an ad. I don't know how much interest there is in duckless ads on the site, but I'm a bit out of touch,

Comment: There was an almost identical question a quarter ago: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/679034/creating-a-map-for-the-info-in-a-document-for-presentation/684629#684629 .

Comment: Watching your „photo“ suggests you may have access to a tool which exports .svg … which you could use to design your picture. Look for svg.path in the tikz manual to include it, at least in parts.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a lazy one

Answer (score 2):

The target picture has shapes with sort of glowing or fuzzy boundaries. While fuzzy circles are part of the standard tikz package, making arbitrary boundaries fuzzy requires somewhat more efforts. Luckily there is a new game in town, the `nfold` library, which greatly helps accomplishing something of that sort. The only reason why I am writing this "answer" is that I wanted to toy with this new tool. One can change the parameters etc. but as a proof of principle the results may be acceptable.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,nfold,shapes.misc}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[fuzzy border/.style={save path=\FuzzyBorder,draw=none,append after command=\pgfextra{\begingroup
    \path[fill=#1,use path=\FuzzyBorder];
    \pgfsetlinewidth{0.2pt}
    \foreach \mypathindex in {1,...,10}{\pgfoffsetpathindex{\FuzzyBorder}{0.9pt}{6-\mypathindex}{10}\pgfmathparse{0.55-0.05*\mypathindex}\pgfsetstrokeopacity{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfusepathqstroke}\endgroup}},
    rr/.style n args={3}{alias=rr,rounded rectangle,fuzzy border=#1,inner xsep=4em,inner ysep=1ex,align=left,font=\sffamily,minimum height=3.5em,text=white,append after command={(rr.west)node[right=1ex,circle,circular glow,fill=white,minimum size=2.5em]{#2}
    (rr.east)node[left=1ex,text=white]{#3}}}]
 \path foreach \Color/\LeftSymbol/\RightSymbol/\Text [count=\Z] in {yellow/\faMobilePhone/\faCamera/30,%
 orange/{\faBattery[0]}/\faVideoCamera/40,%
 magenta/{\faBattery[1]}/\faRocket/50,%
 purple/{\faBattery[2]}/\faSearch/60,%
 cyan/{\faBattery[3]}/\faShoppingBasket/70} {
    ({6*cos(asin((3-\Z)/3))},{1.5*(3-\Z)}) node[rr={\Color}{\LeftSymbol}{\RightSymbol}]{{\large \Text\%}\\[-1ex]{\tiny SERVICE TO BE ADDED} }
 };
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Needless to say that I did not pay particular attention to completing the picture.

Comment: A much cleaner way will be to draw the fuzzy boundary via decorations using `nfold`...